# git clone too slow when downloading

Tags: git

I'm using Windows 10 and the download from git clone is too slow.

[image]

Comment: SO is not an ISP or GitHub tech support. Please direct your questions to them.

Comment: Too slow for what?

Comment: Define `too slow`.  In any case, even if the clone takes some time, it is likely that the time you spend using Git day-to-day will be much less.  When you clone you are basically downloading every file.

Comment: i used to have this kind of problem before, but i forgot how i did the fix back then. i think it is about the usage of ssl/https and i have to use http instead but i can't seem to find a config to change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's your internet problem. You can check if a `git shallow clone` is enough for you: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone

Answer (score 0):

yes git cloning very slow issue you will face when your git file is to large.
so for solving this issue execute below command which is alias of git. this command increase the downloading speed.

alias git=git.exe

after execution of above command issue solved.
[here is picture of solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVbJb.png)

Comment: Highlight the command